# How to validate a string to have only certain letters by perl and regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for a perl regex which will validate a string containing only the letters ACGT. For example "AACGGGTTA" should be valid while "AAYYGGTTA" should be invalid, since the second string has "YY" which is not one of A,C,G,T letters. I have the following code, but it validates both the above strings

```
if($userinput =~/[A|C|G|T]/i)
{
    $validEntry = 1;
    print "Valid\n";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: do you really mean to use /i, allowing either upper or lower case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a character class, and make sure you check the whole string by using the start of string token, `\A`, and end of string token, `\z`.

You should also use `*` or `+` to indicate how many characters you want to match -- `*` means "zero or more" and `+` means "one or more."

Thus, the regex below is saying "between the start and the end of the (case insensitive) string, there should be one or more of the following characters only: a, c, g, t"

```
if($userinput =~ /\A[acgt]+\z/i)
{
    $validEntry = 1;
    print "Valid\n";
}
```

Comment: `$` by default matches the end of the string or before a newline at the end of the string, so your regex matches strings that have newlines too.  To match only the end of the string, use `\z`

Comment: Sure. Nothing in the question specified any particular requirements for how to handle multi-line strings; so either implementation seems valid, in the absence of more information.

Comment: I thought "validate a string containing only the letters ACGT" was pretty clear

Answer (score 5):

Using the character-counting tr operator:

```
if( $userinput !~ tr/ACGT//c )
{
    $validEntry = 1;
    print "Valid\n";
}
```

`tr/characterset//` counts how many characters in the string are in characterset; with the `/c` flag, it counts how many are *not* in the characterset.  Using `!~` instead of `=~` negates the result, so it will be true if there are no characters not in characterset or false if there are characters not in characterset.

Answer (score 4):

Your character class `[A|C|G|T]` contains `|`. `|` does not stand for alternation in a character class, it only stands for itself. Therefore, the character class would include the `|` character, which is not what you want.

Your pattern is not anchored. The pattern `/[ACGT]+/` would match any string that contains one or more of any of those characters. Instead, you need to anchor your pattern, so that only strings that contain just those characters from beginning to end are matched.

`$` can match a newline. To avoid that, use `\z` to anchor at the end. `\A` anchors at the beginning (although it doesn't make a difference whether you use that or `^` in this case, using `\A` provides a nice symmetry.

So, you check should be written:

```
if ($userinput =~ /\A [ACGT]+ \z/ix)
{
    $validEntry = 1;
    print "Valid\n";
}
```